# XUnit Using a Dictionary As MemberData

Tags: c#, xunit

I am having trouble with the syntax of how to get an XUnit Test Method to accept a dictionary as a paramater. This is my code which is broken:

```
Public static Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" }, { "ca", "3" } };
public static object[] dicList = new object[] { vals };

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(dicList))]

public void CheckSomething_ReturnsSomething(Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
 test stuff...
```

I am getting an error I understand from the error thrown that I need a return type of

```
IEnumerable<object[]>
```

I am unsure of how to achieve this with a dictionary.

Have added some code as suggested: I am still getting an error:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" }, { "ca", "3" } };
public static IEnumerable<object[]> dicList = new List<object[]> { new object[] { vals } };
[Theory]
[MemberData(dicList)] //error here 
    public void DriverLogon_CheckParams(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
    }
```

The new error is

```
error. "Cannot convert from IEnumerable<object[]> To string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dicList must be an `IEnumerable<object[]>` like the error message says. This is because one item in the dicList contains all the parameter values for one test (this doesn't matter for your case since you only have one parameter, but it's good to know).

So your dicList becomes a `List<object[]>` instead of just plain object array:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" }, { "ca", "3" } };
public static IEnumerable<object[]> dicList = new List<object[]> { new object[] { vals } };
```

Comment: I used your code and have an error. "Cannot convert from IEnumerable<object[]> to string.

Comment: @PaulStanley the proposed solution works just fine, every item in `object[]` corresponds to parameter in test method, `Dictionary<string, string>` in your case. Otherwise please share the rest of code, which causes an error

Comment: @PaulStanley the dicList is an IEnumerable of object array and in *each* array are values that go into test method as arguments. So if you have 1 object[] in the `dicList`, the test is run once. If you have 2, then the test is run twice with first test using values of dicList[0] and the second test using values from dicList[1].

Comment: Thanks have added more code to show where the error is:)

Comment: @PaulStanley the MemberData attribute takes the *name* of the member, so it should be `[MemberData(nameof(dicList))]` (I think you had it correctly in the original code example).